# How can I check with which options was program compiled?

Tags: linux, gcc, configuration, makefile, configure

I would like to know options which where passed to program before make, which is currently installed on my Ubuntu (from deb). I would like to compile it manualy with the same options (+ some extra).

Comment: ServerFault would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what package the program came from (use `dpkg -S` to find this out), you can `apt-get source $SOURCEPACKAGENAME` (use `apt-cache show` to find this out) the source package and study the build script in `debian/rules`, which controls how the package is configured, built and split into `.deb`s.